# HBase Master is showing in Transition state

Tags: hbase

In HBase, Master is in Transition state and found many of the region in Transition. How to fix it and what could be the reason?

we tried assign the region and region state went to `FAILED_OPEN` state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the problematic  cluster, can you please run:
1. hbase hbck -fixReferencesFiles (This will clear inconsistencies) 
2. hbase hbck -fixAssignments (And check if you can assign the regions to the region server)
3. Once the inconsistencies are cleared, please check the replication status

i hope this should resolve this (ERROR: Found lingering reference file)

Comment: Hi Britto, after ran these 2 commands my hbase inconsistencies has gone and am able to assign regions to region server. my pbm is fixed now. thanks for your solution .